# How to set a delay for L.Tooltip display?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip

I am wondering how to set a delay for tooltip visualization on mouse hover. I haven't found such a feature in options description in docs.

My map is crowded with many markers, so when mouse is moving around, all the time some tooltips appear. My idea is to set some delay, so that for example after 1 second of hovering, tooltip for this particular marker to be displayed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to have the delay function, so I grabed it from the old Tooltip plugin and made a quick workaround, it probably can be done way better, but I have no time to improve it.

I extended the bindtooltip, open and close methods and added the 'showDelay' and 'hideDelay' properties to the L.Layer class. I added a click event to close the tooltip at the "initTooltipInteractions' too, because it made sense in my specific situation, but you can take it off.

Just add this to a javascript file and load it after leaflet:

```
 L.Layer.include({

     showDelay: 1200,
     hideDelay: 100,

     bindTooltipDelayed: function (content, options) {

         if (content instanceof L.Tooltip) {
             L.setOptions(content, options);
             this._tooltip = content;
             content._source = this;
         } else {
             if (!this._tooltip || options) {
                 this._tooltip = new L.Tooltip(options, this);
             }
             this._tooltip.setContent(content);

         }

         this._initTooltipInteractionsDelayed();

         if (this._tooltip.options.permanent && this._map && this._map.hasLayer(this)) {
             this.openTooltipWithDelay();
         }

         return this;
     },

     _openTooltipDelayed: function (e) {
         var layer = e.layer || e.target;

         if (!this._tooltip || !this._map) {
             return;
         }
         this.openTooltipWithDelay(layer, this._tooltip.options.sticky ? e.latlng : undefined);
     },

     openTooltipDelayed: function (layer, latlng) {
         if (!(layer instanceof L.Layer)) {
             latlng = layer;
             layer = this;
         }
         if (layer instanceof L.FeatureGroup) {
             for (var id in this._layers) {
                 layer = this._layers[id];
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (!latlng) {
             latlng = layer.getCenter ? layer.getCenter() : layer.getLatLng();
         }
         if (this._tooltip && this._map) {
             this._tooltip._source = layer;
             this._tooltip.update();
             this._map.openTooltip(this._tooltip, latlng);
             if (this._tooltip.options.interactive && this._tooltip._container) {
                 addClass(this._tooltip._container, 'leaflet-clickable');
                 this.addInteractiveTarget(this._tooltip._container);
             }
         }

         layer.fireEvent('mousemove', lastMouseEvent);

         return this;
     },
     openTooltipWithDelay: function (t, i) {
         this._delay(this.openTooltipDelayed, this, this.showDelay, t, i);
     },
     closeTooltipDelayed: function () {
         if (this._tooltip) {
             this._tooltip._close();
             if (this._tooltip.options.interactive && this._tooltip._container) {
                 removeClass(this._tooltip._container, 'leaflet-clickable');
                 this.removeInteractiveTarget(this._tooltip._container);
             }
         }
         return this;
     },
     closeTooltipWithDelay: function () {
         clearTimeout(this._timeout);
         this._delay(this.closeTooltipDelayed, this, this.hideDelay);
     },
     _delay: function (func, scope, delay, t, i) {
         var me = this;
         if (this._timeout) {
             clearTimeout(this._timeout)
         }
         this._timeout = setTimeout(function () {
             func.call(scope, t, i);
             delete me._timeout
         }, delay)
     },
     _initTooltipInteractionsDelayed: function (remove$$1) {
         if (!remove$$1 && this._tooltipHandlersAdded) { return; }
         var onOff = remove$$1 ? 'off' : 'on',
            events = {
                remove: this.closeTooltipWithDelay,
                move: this._moveTooltip
            };
         if (!this._tooltip.options.permanent) {
             events.mouseover = this._openTooltipDelayed;
             events.mouseout = this.closeTooltipWithDelay;
             events.click = this.closeTooltipWithDelay;
             if (this._tooltip.options.sticky) {
                 events.mousemove = this._moveTooltip;
             }
             if (L.touch) {
                 events.click = this._openTooltipDelayed;
             }
         } else {
             events.add = this._openTooltipDelayed;
         }
         this[onOff](events);
         this._tooltipHandlersAdded = !remove$$1;
     }
 });
```

And then to use it:

```
layer.showDelay = 800; //use 0 for no delay behavior
layer.hideDelay = 2000; //use 0 for normal behavior
layer.bindTooltipDelayed("text", tooltipOptions);
```